# How to connect Windows 8 App into Ms crm 2011 offline?

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, dynamics-crm-2011

I connected windows 8 App into ms crm 2011 online and the functionality is working fine.
And next i want to connect the ms crm 2011 offline, is there any way to connect offline.whenever come online it should sync to CRM and update the records.Please suggest the solution

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is "baked in" to Outlook, but I don't believer there are any APIs associated with it.  I'm assuming you'll need to "roll your own" logic for updating and syncing back to CRM when the client is able to connect to CRM again.